Alternative Geometric Construction of Minkowski Space Metric
In the Minkowski Space, at each point, we define a tangent space, and using the metric construct, we calculate a real number that shows the infinitesimal invariant interval between two points. This real number, based on a convention, has three possible values, zero for a lightlike path, positive for timelike, and negative for spacelike separated paths. We can think of it as a function or map that assigns to each point of the manifold a value on the real line. 
Can we alternatively interpret this function defined over the manifold like the one described below:?
At each point of the manifold, there is a light cone, where all points on it are projected to a single point on the real line.
Similarly, for each point on any timelike or spacelike path or curve, the beginning and ending points of the curve, two events, are projected to two distinct points on the real line, showing the positive or negative values.
 
Can we use the above observation, and make sense of the spacetime manifold as a fiber bundle, the total space, over the real line as the base manifold?
Can we think of the fibers of this bundle as the lightlike paths that any movement along them will be projected to a single point on the real line?
Because we have not used any coordinate chart here, isn't the invariant interval between any two points already manifest geometrically?

You posted the same  in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/811403/geometric-construction-of-minkowski-space-and-proper-time

Would it be possible to see more geometric answer rather than a physical, or this is not allowed here?

You got an answer, which told you many wrong parts! It has nothing to do with geometry

None of your questions seem to do with geometry, so I think this belongs in the physics exchange. Seeing as it is already answered there...this probably can be closed unless the question is updated to reflect what the specific geometry question is.

update attempted

Your question is unclear, but you should note the following: (2) probably means "consider a real line bundle $E\to M$." (3) Bundles over contractible spaces are trivial, thus, you are just taking the product $P=E\times \mathbb R$ and regard it as a bundle over $\mathbb R$.  Starting with the sentence "In step 4, the fiber, represents the light-like path rather than the coordinate time.", I cannot make sense of your writing.

@MoisheKohan, question revised.

Now it makes even less sense. My suggestion is to read O'Neil's book "Semi-Riemannian geometry" to clear various misconceptions that you have.

I can take this comment as an answer, if you just note one of the misconception that I have.

Start with "we calculate a real number that shows the infinitesimal invariant interval between two points." Next, "We can think of it as a function or map that assigns to each point of the manifold a value on the real line."

@MoisheKohan I see that you are saying it is not a function at all, because it is a form that gets two tangent vectors as input, returns a real value that depends on the vectors fed into the form, not the point itself, right?
